# Jqgrid table format not showing in user pages in drupal7

Tags: views, javascript

I tried to create a table inside a view in jqgrid format. But when tried to display it in a view in user page (user-profile.tpl.php) the table is not showing. Is any coding needed for that?, it showing perfectly when I change the format to simple table in view.

Thanks in advance